# unable to run wifi in ubuntu 16.04.

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers

I recently installed 16.04 version of ubuntu but the problem is that I am unable to use wifi as is doesn't show option to select network. I had dual booted this ubuntu with windows 10 and wifi works well with windows. i had qualcomm artheros driver being installed in windows and it run perfecty in my windows. I had seen many answers regarding wifi issue but nothing happened. In my software update panel under additional settings my wifi card is not recognised. Nothing is shown there. some solutions said run apt-get commands but i can't bcoz i can't run net. Nothing happened can anybody help me to solve my issue? anyone can suggest me a way to install wifi driver using terminal or some other method.If anyone know the solution or want more details about the error can leave a comment. I will provide all the neccesory details as soon as possible.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep ath`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Use hardwired network connection while trying to TS the wireless.  I had to do that while resolving my wifi card issues in Linux.